# How to set a view for AlertDialog in android?

Tags: android, xml, dialog, android-alertdialog

I want to set a custom view for my alert dialog. Actually I have a grid view and I want to show a dialog when each item clicked, I built a function as ToastWarning and it builds my alert dialog. This is my xml for custom view: an imageview, textview and 2 button:

But this code is not working.why?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/linear_toast" 
android:gravity="right"
android:background="@drawable/white"

>
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:gravity="right"
>
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_Toast"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_toast"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

     />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:gravity="right"
android:weightSum="10"
android:padding="5dp">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_no"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_yes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It's my code for building a alert dialog:

```
private void ToastWarning() {
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast, null);

iv_alert=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.iv_toast);
            tv_alert=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_Toast);
            bt_yes=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.bt_yes);
            bt_yes=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.bt_no);
            iv_alert.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.facebook);

            tv_alert.setTypeface(face);
            bt_yes.setTypeface(face);
            bt_no.setTypeface(face);
            bt_yes.setText(PersianReshape.reshape("بله"));
            bt_no.setText(PersianReshape.reshape("خیر"));
            tv_alert.setText(PersianReshape.reshape("فیلدهای مورد نظر پر شود."));

AlertDialog MyDialog;
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setView(view);
            MyDialog=builder.create();
            MyDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: what is the problem? what is your mean about ` not working`?

Comment: the problem is when i click,it's force closing

Comment: where is click listener? you must first setClickListener on your button

Comment: in my grid view and in function of onItemclick when each item of grid view has been clicked i wanna show alert dialog and i wrote code of setonClicklistener

Comment: force close while clicking on `GridView` item or on `yes,no` Click?

Comment: force close while clicking on GridView..well i changed my xml and use one Relativelayout and still it didnt work but when i deleted 2 buttons it worked,why?

Comment: did you test `PersianReshape.reshape` before ? is this worked fine ?

Comment: finally i found my stupid mistake

Comment: bt_yes=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.bt_yes);
            bt_yes=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.bt_no);   this was my mistake